# Ionic app - the app references non-public selectors in Payload determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler:, lookupAdConversionDetails"

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular7

Unable to upload ionic 4 app to the apple app store ( Xcode version - **14.2 (14C18)** ). we are getting below error.

**the app references non-public selectors in Payload determineAppInstallationAttributionWithCompletionHandler:, lookupAdConversionDetails".**

Below are the app informations.

> **Installed plugin - **

[image]

> **Ionic Info -**

[image]

Any help, much appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the Firebase plugin. I was using old FCM plugin **"cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated : 4.1.1"** due to which the podFile in the iOS platform has lower version to support on Xcode 14

**old pod file**

> pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 6.3.0' (`platform/ios/PodFile`)

After I update the FCM plugin **"cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated : 7.8.0"** and add the iOS platform again, it updates the podfile automatically.

**new pod file**

> pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 7.4.0' (`platform/ios/PodFile`)

---

Below are the Steps to fix the issue

1. Remove the ios platform (`ionic cordova platform rm ios`).
2. Remove the old FCM plugin (`ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated`).
3. Add updated plugin 7.4.0 (`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated@7.4.0`).
4. Add ios platform again (`ionic cordova platform add ios`) - This will automatically update the podfile in ios platform.
5. Build app and release app to the app store.